# Can anyone help me find the bug in this C function?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, cstring

So, I have written a mystrstr() function which should behave exactly as the original strstr() function. 
I have tested huge amount of cases and my function seems to work. However, it does not pass some of the tests of the online submission system.

Can you help me?

```
int mystrcmp(char *a, char *b)
{
    int n = mystrlen(a);
    int m = mystrlen(b);
    int l = n;
    if (m<n) l = m;

    //printf("strcmp => %d %d\n", n, m);
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        //printf("%c %c\n",a[i],b[i]);
        if (a[i]<b[i]) return -2;
        else if (a[i]>b[i]) return 2;
    }

    if (n<m) return -1;
    else if (n>m) return 1;
    else return 0;
}


char *mystrstr(char *haystack, char *needle)
{
    int n = mystrlen(haystack);
    int m = mystrlen(needle);
    if (n==0&&m==0) return haystack;
    int result;

    for (int i=0; i<=(n-m); i++)
    {
        result = mystrcmp(haystack+i, needle);
        if (result==1||result==0||result==-1)
            return haystack+i;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What tests fail? What is the input and incorrect output? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Well, that is the problem. They are private test cases, which are not revealed to us.

Comment: Well, for all we know then, the tests are invalid, and this question cannot be answered.

Comment: @AzadSalahli You can't compile your own program for testing?

Comment: If, by invalid test, you are referring to the online submission system, you are wrong, because another implementation passes all the tests.

Comment: Removed homework tag as it's [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: Also, you should probably ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @John, Program compiles and works. But there is a test case that my program gives wrong answer, and I don't know the test case itself, since it is not revealed to us.

Comment: No checks for NULL pointers. Perhaps it is that...

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe One of the conditions should be removed, but it is intended to take advantage of the particular behavior of `mystrcmp()` that returns 1 or -1 for when a string is a prefix of the other.

Comment: @WilliamMorris, strstr() function itself doesn't allow NULL parameters.

Comment: Are there time limits on the test cases? If so, your implementation might simply be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `mystrcmp` is redundant.  You can just use

```
if (!memcmp(haystack+i, needle, m)) {
     return haystack+i
}
```

If you are not allowed to use `memcmp` then write your own. But discard `mystrcmp`.

Comment: I believe that is what you are talking about: `mystrstr("abcd","");` . It actually returns "abcd", which is the expected result.

Comment: About `mystrcmp`. I was required to write it as part of my homework. As long as it works, I don't have problem with it. But, I am curious, what is the difference between using `memcmp` and `strcmp`?

Comment: `memcmp` has a simpler job than `strcmp` as it must only check a known number of bytes for equivalence; `strcmp` must worry about not going beyond the end of each string.  Yes, your function does work with needle=="". Sorry!

Answer (score -4):

```
if (n==0&&m==0) return haystack;
```

You want "||" operator.

```
if (m<n) l = m;
```

You know if "m != n" then the two string do not have equal length, hence are not equal.

Not sure about the rest, didn't look to much further.

Comment: “You know if "m != n" then the two string do not have equal length, hence are not equal” Yes, but the goal of function `strcmp` is not just to tell if the strings are equal. It is to order them. In the particular case of this implementation, a third function is obviously to tell if one is a prefix of the other.

Comment: “You want "||" operator.” No, if m==2, n==0, the function should not return `haystack`.

Comment: `if (n==0&&m==0) return haystack;`
That's not correct, since if n=0 and m!=0, I want to return NULL